# error in template declaration

Tags: c++

I am getting "error: cannot declare pointer to 'void' member" for below code.

```
 template  <class T>
    DtRequestId Notify(T* pObject, void (T::*callback)(Status*));
```

can somebody please help?

Comment: If only there wasn't already an answer :P

Comment: Sorry ;) Some folks just like solving problems no matter whose they are :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error when I compile this (whole file):

```
typedef int DtRequestId;
template  <class T>
    DtRequestId Notify(T* pObject, void (T::*callback)(Status*));
```

But if I also define `Status`, the error goes away:

```
typedef int DtRequestId;
typedef int Status;
template  <class T>
    DtRequestId Notify(T* pObject, void (T::*callback)(Status*));
```

So maybe you forgot to give a definition of `Status`.